# how to install adobe AIR 3.9 in flash CS6

Tags: flash, air

I downloaded the installer of the last AIR SDK on the adobe site. It gave me a installer. I ran it and it told me everything was installed properly.

Problem : I don't know where.

When I use the "Manage AIR SDK" in the help menu of Flash CS6 I'm prompted to select a AIR SDK but I don't know where to go !

Somebody can help me on this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I downloaded the Adobe AIR, not the Adobe AIR SDK.

I feel sooo stupid.